# Specify SSH configuration for Git per-repository

Tags: git, mercurial, ssh

In Mercurial, I can specify the command (and thus the certificate) used for SSH per-repository in `.hg/hgrc`, for example:

```
[ui]
...
ssh = "C:\path\to\ssh.exe" -i "C:\Development\Identities\identity1.id_rsa"
```

Most instructions I can find on configuring Git seem to use the bundled `ssh.exe` to manage the certificates, for example [GitHub's guide for Windows](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/). There is a way of specifying a script for Git to use for SSL ([here](http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/) under "No supported authentication methods available") via an environment variable, but that per user and not granular enough for me.

How can I specify a per-repository SSH command line in Git?

Comment: https://dev.to/web3coach/how-to-configure-a-local-git-repository-to-use-a-specific-ssh-key-4aml this worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to make `git` do this.  But `ssh` should be flexible enough to do it instead.

First note that you can specify more than one identity file.  It will try multiple identities in turn, until one is accepted.

Second, under unix, if you want only certain identities to be tried for certain hosts, you can do so by modifying `~/.ssh/config` to have stanzas such as:

```
Host <hostname>
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     IdentityFile "C:\Development\Identities\identity1.id_rsa"
```

Though I don't know if that will work for your bundled windows ssh client, or where the config file goes, if it does.

EDIT: if you want to use two different identities on the same host, that can be done too:

```
Host <alias1>
     HostName <realhostname>
     IdentiesOnly yes
     IdentityFile identity1


Host <alias2>
     HostName <realhostname>
     IdentiesOnly yes
     IdentityFile identity2
```

and use  and  as the hosts in `git` (there is substantial support to treat one host as another, or do even stronger rewriting with config options such as `url.<base>.insteadOf`.

Comment: Thanks, that works well although it isn't what I was hoping for. I also had issues with multiple installations of Git, I ended up uninstalling all of them except for Cygwin's, which is pretty sane and uses `c:\cygwin\home\[USERNAME]\.ssh\config`.